# Why am I getting a re-definition error in C++?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, declaration

I wrote a `Fraction` class to do some work with `Fraction` objects and overloading and such and I need to separate the implementation from the definitions of the methods but I get a redefinition error when it comes to the constructors of the class `Fraction`.

Code snippet from **Fraction.h**

```
class Fraction
{
private:
   int calcGCD(int n1, int n2) const;
   int compare(const Fraction& fraction) const;
   int m_numerator;
   int m_denominator;
public:
   Fraction(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1) : m_numerator(numerator), m_denominator(denominator);
   Fraction(const Fraction& fraction) : m_numerator(fraction.numerator()), m_denominator(fraction.denominator());
   Fraction(const Fraction& orig);
};
```

Code snippet from **Fraction.cpp**

```
#include "Fraction.h"

Fraction::Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) 
   : m_numerator(numerator), m_denominator(denominator)
{}

Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction& fraction)
   : m_numerator(fraction.numerator()), m_denominator(fraction.denominator())
{}
```

This is resulting in the following errors:

```
Fraction.h:26:5: error: 'Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction&)' cannot be overloaded with 'Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction&)'
Fraction.h:25:5: note: previous declaration 'Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction&)'
Fraction.h:24:105: error: expected '{' at end of input
```

Followed by some others which I think are just a cascading effect of one or two main errors. But I can post them if really needed.

I think it has something to do with how I'm declaring the constructor in the `.cpp` file because I know some things do not carry over such as access modifiers and `static` and etc.

Sorry if this is a silly error, I am new to C++ and I can not find the answer anywhere.

Comment: You already implemented `Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction &fraction)` in the header.

Comment: You have 2 constructors for fraction that take the same argument `const Fraction &`

Comment: What exactly do you think is the difference between `Fraction(const Fraction &fraction) : m_numerator(fraction.numerator()), m_denominator(fraction.denominator());` and `Fraction(const Fraction& orig);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in the code you posted.

First, the copy constructor is *declared* twice in the header file. Both these declarations are the same because their parameters are of the same type.

```
Fraction(const Fraction& fraction);
Fraction(const Fraction& orig);
```

Secondly, the constructors are *defined* twice: once in the header file, once in the source file. There can be only one definition. You can choose which one to keep. I usually prefer to define them in the source file (.cpp) in order to hide the implementation details.

Finally, if you keep the definition in the header file, a pair of brackets is missing. A valid implementation in the header file would look like this:

```
class Fraction {      
private:
    ...
    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;
public:
    Fraction(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1) : m_numerator(numerator), m_denominator(denominator) {}
    Fraction(const Fraction &fraction) : m_numerator(fraction.numerator()), m_denominator(fraction.denominator()) {}
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay I removed one of the copy constructors. I didn't realize netbeans had put that there. But What do you mean by the constructors being implemented in the header file? I didn't add a body to any of them.

Comment: Take a look at the first example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

The `: m_numerator(numerator), m_denominator(denominator)` part, called a member initializer list, is part of the definition of the constructor. It is not part of the declaration, and thus doesn't have to be repeated in both the header and the source files.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tqu5yy      Is this all I had to do? Because I'm still getting an error about brackets.   Sorry, I checked the link you sent but all their examples had code in the same file. My program works perfectly when its all in the same file.

Answer (score 5):

You have declared the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) twice.

```
Fraction(const Fraction& fraction) ....
Fraction(const Fraction& orig);
```

Look at the signature. They are same, which can not be possible in C++.

You probably meant in the **Fraction.h**

```
Fraction(const Fraction &fraction); // only one
```

and in the **Fraction.cpp**

```
Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction& fraction)
   : m_numerator(fraction.numerator())
   , m_denominator(fraction.denominator())
{}
```

In short, you need to remove one of them.